# How to procedural digital camo?

Tags: shaders

I attempted to use brick texture but plugging a noise or any other texture into Bias input would not bias the colors I chose in the node to randomize based on the texture.
What I want to do: plug a noise texture (relatively large one) into brick texture(no mortar, square bricks) to create "digital camo" effect (large chunks of colors with blocky borders). Did not work, how should I do it?[image: What I want to get]

[image: What I am getting]

Answer (score 18):

You don't want to use a bricks texture to make your output all blocky.  Instead, snap your texture coordinates using a vector math node:

[image]

If we specifically wanted to use a noise texture to create camo (that was blocky), we might use the noise fac to mix between three colors like this:

[image]

Noise output isn't evenly distributed, so you'll want to tune the numbers in the "greater than" nodes to eye-- it's not as if 0.33, 0.67 will get equal frequency of all three colors.

However, I wouldn't recommend making camo via noise.  Instead, I would make it with voronoi texture:

[image]

Voronoi creates cells that all have the same position output (voronoi basically calculates the distance to the nearest semi-randomly generated point; "position" is the location of that point.)  We can get a random from that position with a white noise node, and then mix between our three colors on the basis of the output.  Because each voronoi cell has a consistent position, our random numbers are also going to be consistent across the cell.  White noise *does* have a flat distribution, so 0.33, 0.67 will get us even frequencies of our three colors.

There are plenty of ways to mix this up to get what you want.  We could combine noise and voronoi, with the noise creating a bit of variation in the voronoi (or distorting the coordinates); we could use multiple voronoi, with offset, to calculate overlaid camo spots; etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pixelate your shader- here's a good tutorial https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/texture-pixelization/
You could also Pixelate with the compositor- https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/filter/pixelate.html